# Displaying data in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I have a view that displays all the objects in my data, and I do so in the template using the `{% for object in objects %}` tag. But I think when this is converted to html every object is then surrounded by a `<p>` tag? But the issue is that I want to display the objects in pairs of two. Not a vertical list of 1 element. How can I loop through an array in Django and be able to customize where they are laid out? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Django does not automatically put p tags around template elements. If that is happening, you must be doing it yourself in your template. Perhaps you should slow that template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In a `{% for object in objects%}`, if I say `{ object.name }` will that not have a `<p>` tag around it?

Comment: No, not unless you put it there yourself, or object.name contains that tag itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in template tag for pairing objects consecutively so you have two options; either you can write your own template tag which converts a list of objects like `(a, b, c, d)` to a lists of **two-element** tuples like `((a, b), (c, d))`, or create two pairs in your view just before rendering the template.

```
import itertools

def object_list(request):
    ...
    iterator = iter(objects)
    pairs = itertools.izip_longest(*(iterator, iterator))
    return render(request, 'objects/object_list.html', {'objects': objects, 'pairs': pairs})
```

In your template, you can iterator over pairs as follows;

```
{% for first, second in pairs %}
  <p>{{first}}, {{second}}</p>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem.